simple example of jacobian of elliptic curve
Suppose I have a genus $1$ curve $C$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ given by say $y^2=x^3+1$. How do I find the variety $Aut(C_{\mathbb{C}})$, which is also the Jacobian of $C$? It should be an elliptic curve, maybe $C$ itself, but I'm struggling to bit understanding concretely what the definitions are.

Yes, any elliptic curve is isomorphic to its Jacobian. I'm not sure about your claim that the Jacobian is the same as the automorphism group; maybe you mean the connected component of the identity in the automorphism group?

Yes, something like that. Do you know a simple source where this is explained? I'm not very familiar with these things

I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for, but you could try Shafarevich Volume 1 where something like this is explained in Theorem III.3.1.
